# How to pipe output from cat to cut

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I want to `cat /proc/uptime` into `cut -f1` in a Bash script.

I've tried;

```
cat /proc/uptime | cut -f1
cat /proc/uptime > cut -f1
cut -f1 < cat /proc/uptime
```

Do I need to use echo or something else to make this happen?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? It's difficult to tell from that one-liner. The first one is correct [but unnecessary](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) as `cut` takes [FILE] as command-line parameter.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to cat the results of uptime in seconds. I only want the first field of output from /proc/uptime

Comment: Figured it out! I needed to specify the delimiter.... I thought that was set default to space. My one-liner looks like this now: cat /proc/uptime | cut -d' ' -f1

Comment: It made sense after I fixed your markdown. :) You can also do this with Awk, and is IMO, easier to remember. `awk '{ print $1 }' /proc/uptime`

Comment: http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html

Answer (score 8):

The default field delimiter for `cut` is a tab. Since your file has a space instead, you need to specify the delimiter:

```
-d ' '
```

And you really don't need to use `cat` or a pipe at all. Just read the file directly.

```
cut -f 1 -d ' ' /proc/uptime
```

Comment: Bonus:

How would I then do a `if [ output -lt specified time]` then do this in bash...

Comment: @brenguy That would be an entirely separate question. Here we prefer distinct questions to be asked separately, as this is not a forum and not intended to be.

Answer (score 4):

```
cat /proc/uptime | cut -f1 -d' '
```

is **correct**

```
< /proc/uptime  cut -f1 -d' '
```

is **correct** and more efficient as it reads from `/proc/uptime` directly without creating a pipe (not that it matters here much).

It's generally advisable to use the second form on forums, or else you'll get purists coming after you shouting "useless use of cat".

---

```
cut -f1 -d' ' < cat /proc/uptime
```

is **wrong**.
It's the same as

```
cut -f1 -d' ' /proc/uptime < cat
```

---

If you're in bash, you can also use `<()`:

```
cut -f1 -d' ' < <(cat /proc/uptime)
```

This creates an anonymous named pipe for reading and the output of `cat /proc/uptime` will be piped into it. But again—useless use of cat.

Other than that, `cut` can also take a file argument so all the redirect versions will also work without the `<` (it shouldn't matter efficiency-wise):

```
cut -f1 -d' '/proc/uptime
```

Or with the <() pipe:

```
cut -f1 -d' ' <(cat /proc/uptime)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the delimiter for cut is TAB, you could change it to be whitespace with

```
cat /proc/uptime | cut -f1 -d " "
```

Although in those cases I prefer to use awk:

```
cat /proc/uptime | awk '{print$1}'
```

Comment: I am going to create a shell. You'll have to opt-in of course, but every pipe results in a donation to charity from $USER's bank account.